# how to get full path of attachment in office outlook add in?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, email-attachments

Is there any way to get the full path of an outlook add in attachment? Checking the api I only find that it returns the content of the file. I need the path to pass it to a third party library.

Comment: Do you develop a COM or web add-in for Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule attachments are not saved automatically to the disk until users open them. So, you need to save the attached file to the disk first. Typically attachments are kept in the data store in the Outlook profile.

If you develop a COM add-in you need to save the attached file on the disk by using the [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method and then pass the file path to a third-party library.

But in case of web add-ins there is no disk APIs due to security reasons (web add-ins are run in a sandboxed environment), so you may pass the attachment content to any web service for processing, see [Get attachments of an Outlook item from the server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item) for more information.

Comment: The add in must work in both the desktop and web versions. It is a mailtag that shows the attachement under some criteria. But what I can't find in the documentation is how to get the path of the files uploaded from the PC.

Comment: The `OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that. Outlook may store such just attached files in the cache folder. See [Outlook SecureTemp Files Folder](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/securetemp-files-folder/#:~:text=In%20Vista%2C%20Windows%207%2F8,%5CTemporary%20Internet%20Files%5CContent.) for more information.

Comment: The client wants the add-in to be cross-platform, do we know where outlook saves these temporary files in ios or andriod?

Comment: Nope. There is no information per platform. Only the desktop edition of Outlook exposes such path.

Comment: Again, only if such attachments are opened by users or attached to an email.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not store attachments as files. They are stored inside the mailbox and only exist in the context of the parent messages.

Comment: So there is no way to get the original path of these attaches in the context of the parent messages?

Comment: That is correct. On the Extended MAPI level (which is the native Outlook API on Windows) attachments know nothing about files. Their data is only accessed through streams (`IStream`).